# Composite of relation and its opposite

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I have a relation set $R = \{(a, b), (a, c), (b, c), (b, d), (c, d), (c, a)\}$ included in set $\{a, b, c, d\}\times\{a, b, c, d\}$.

Its opposite of relation is $R^{−1} = \{(b, a), (c, a), (c, b), (d, b), (d, c), (a, c)\}$.

I'm asked to find the composite of $R\circ R^{−1}$ as a set, and I came up with:

> $R\circ R^{−1} = \{(a, a), (a, d), (b, b), (b, c), (c, b), (c, c), (d, c), (d, d), (d, a)\}$.

However, the practice exam's answer says it is:

> $R\circ R^{−1} = \{(a, a), (b, b), (c, c), (d, d), (a, d), (d, c)\}$

After that, I'm asked to find $R^{−1}\circ R$, which I came up with to be:

> $R^{−1}\circ R = \{(a, c), (a, a), (a, b), (b, a), (b, b), (b, c), (c, c), (c, b)\}$

Whereas again the practice exam's solution tells me:

> $R^{−1}\circ R = \{(a, a), (b, b), (c, c), (d, b), (d, c)\}$

Who is correct? I came to my answers by drawing out arrow diagrams and followed the each member of $X$ to its $Y$, but I seem to be getting way more relations than the solution says I should be.

Comment: You may also upvote helpful answers, Harry! (You have the reputation to upvote good/helpful answers, as many as you'd like: click on the $\uparrow$ above the vote count of an answer you'd like to upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text appears to be incorrect.

I was unable to verify your answers.  In one case you seem to be missing one ordered pair and in the other you seem to have one ordered pair too many.

Answer (score 3):

I think the text is wrong. Whoever wrote the question might have been working under the assumption that the relation was injective (one-to-one), in which case you get back the identity relation when you compose $R$ with its inverse (this is what you called the "opposite" relation). However, clearly, $R$ is not injective as $\left(a,b\right)$ and $\left(a,c\right)$ are in $R$.

Comment: Would that mean, assuming the author of the question meant what they wrote down and the solutions are just wrong, that my answers are correct?

Comment: I did not check your answer in great detail, but the first few elements in the composition $R \circ R^{-1}$ are correct. I think you have the right idea, and if you made a mistake, it is not from a lack of understanding.